# Matplotlib axis showing weird behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot these functions using matplotlib

```
def fn_dydx(x):
    return 4 * x ** 3

def fn_diff_dydx(x, delta_val):
    diff_map = {}
    diff_map[0.001] = -1000.0*x**4 + 1000.0*(x + 0.001)**4
    diff_map[0.01] = -100.0 * x ** 4 + 100.0 * (x + 0.01) ** 4
    diff_map[0.1] = -10.0 * x ** 4 + 10.0 * (x + 0.1) ** 4
    diff_map[1] = -1 * x ** 4 + 1.0 * (x + 1) ** 4
    return diff_map[delta_val]
```

Using the following code

```
        line_colors = ['r', 'c', 'y', 'b', 'm']
        plot_range = np.linspace(-2, 2, 4000)
        y_val = fn_dydx(plot_range)

        fig = self.plot.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
        ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        #ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        #ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
        ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
        ax.set_xlabel('x', loc='right')
        ax.set_ylabel('dy/dx', loc='top')
        ax.set_title('Differentiation of y = x^4 using sympy and finite perturbance')

        self.plot.plot(plot_range, y_val, label='dy/dx using sympy', color='k')
        ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1),
                  loc="upper left", fontsize='6')

        for delta, color in zip(delta_range, line_colors):
            y_diff_val = fn_diff_dydx(plot_range, delta)
            self.plot.plot(plot_range, y_diff_val, label=f'dy/dx using perturbance for delta = {delta}', color=color)
            ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1),
                      loc="upper left", fontsize='6')
        self.plot.show()
```

I have initialized the plot parameters as follows

```
        self.plot = matplotlib.pyplot
        font = {'family': 'serif',
                'weight': 'light',
                'size': '6'}
        self.plot.rc('font', **font)
        self.plot.rcParams['figure.constrained_layout.use'] = True
        self.plot.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
        self.plot.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True
        self.plot.rc('xtick', labelsize=6)
        self.plot.rc('ytick', labelsize=6)
        self.plot.rc('axes', labelsize=6)
```

But the resultant plot behaves weirdly(shifts downwards) for the following list of delta_range [1, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]
The output is [image]
I want to fix the given code, to compare all these four equations correctly

Comment: Could you try to explain more clearly what you mean by *"behaves weirdly"*? What did you expect, and how is the plot different? If curves are very close together, a curve drawn later might hide a previous one, isn't that what you'd want?

Comment: Oh sorry, the behaves weirdly in terms why is it shifting downwards?

Comment: The formulas aren't symmetric, so the positive values are higher.  Why do you set `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')` instead of at zero?

Comment: `def fn_diff_dydx(x, delta_val): return ((x+delta_val)**4-x**4)/delta_val` — why not?

Comment: re the observation that the functions are not (anti)symmetric, what about `def d(x,dx): return ((x+dx/2)**4-(x-dx/2)**4)/dx`